# is it possible for me to Co-author research paper(s)/article(s) and get it published?

Tags: professorship

I hold a M.Sc. in Finance from UK and currently live in Toronto, Canada. I want to Co-author research paper(s)/article(s) with a professor/PhD academic and get the paper published in good journal. I want to do this on volunteer basis to gain experience of conducting high quality research and publication. Is this possible in Toronto or Canada?

Answer (score 5):

Is this **possible**?

Yes, it is possible that one could volunteer to co-author something and find someone who is willing to let you do it with them.

Is this **probable** or **likely** in the abstract?

No, it's very unlikely that someone will just take on a co-author who has nothing to offer but their time to the project. What could increase the probability is if you have some thing to contribute to authoring the paper.  For instance, there would need to be some particular feature of your finance knowledge that they lack or would find useful in producing the paper.

Primarily, the issue is that academic researchers in most fields are not looking for apprentices that can watch the research process and then learn how to do research in this way. Instead, they often co-author things with (A) each other by bringing different areas of expertise or (B) graduate students who undertake the research.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not. Anyone with any degree from any country can publish. as long as the publication is up to the standard of the journal.

Comment: well the issue here is to Co-author research article(s) for the sake of not only learning but contributing. Is there any Professor/PhD academic in Finance in Toronto who would be willing to let me Co-author such an article? anyone interested, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I would have phrased this as *Anyone with or without any degree ...*